# Bazel - Should you use the same GCS bucket as remote cache for master and feature branches?

Tags: gitlab-ci, bazel

I just started using Bazel for our team's GitLab CI pipeline, so I wonder if we could use the same GCS bucket as remote cache for `master` and `feature` branches.

My thinking is that it could lead to a race condition if the cache is updated by 2 build job simultaneously. One more scenario is creating docker image right after a build job: it could put the wrong binaries into the Docker image.

Could anyone correct me on that? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel has reproducible builds, so you can be sure that when branches share some code it's identical.

It is possible (although unlikely) that you build the same part twice, but since both builds should give the same result it doesn't matter.